# Understanding Props in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties

Currently working with Props in TypeScript and have some issues Understanding a case:

```
type Props = Readonly<{
  onAnythingChange: (query: string) => void; 
}>
```

how does this property work? I dont get the logic behind it.
Whats the sense of "void"?

Comment: I suggest reviewing [the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) (there's a search feature; typing `void` in it provides useful results), particularly the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html), and going through some tutorials. Picking TypeScript up by posting a question about each thing you don't understand won't be an effective way to learn. FWIW: The type says that the `onAnythingChange` property is a function that accepts one parameter (`query`, a string) and has no meaningful return value (`void`).

Comment: It's worth noting that `void` doesn't mean the function doesn't return anything (and thus implicitly returns `undefined`). Just that the return value isn't meaningful and shouldn't be used.